# Does sidekiq use multiple cpu cores and can it be run on multiple machines?

Tags: sidekiq

Does sidekiq take advantage of multiple cpu cores?

Can I run sidekiq on multiple machines with one redis database and have them all proccess the same queue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sidekiq is limited to whatever Ruby can do. If you are running Sidekiq in MRI Ruby, each Sidekiq process is limited to one core. You can utilize all cores by running multiple MRI processes.

If you are running Sidekiq in JRuby, that one process can take advantage of all cores.

All Sidekiq processes can process any queue, regardless of what machine they are running on.

Comment: So on a 4 core machine with MRI Ruby, we should have 4 processes & scale back concurrency as needed? Does each process know to grab a different core?

Comment: It's more accurate to say that a single MRI process uses one core at a time to run Ruby code. It is not "tied" to a single core; rather, the operating system schedules time on any of the various cores. While Ruby can only be interpreted on one core at a time (thanks to the Global Interpreter Lock), IO can still occur on background threads.

Comment: Even if you have 4 cores, you may be able to launch more Sidekiq processes if your workload is IO-intensive rather than CPU-intensive.